# How long have operating systems automatically "freed" a processes' memory for?

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, operating-system

One of my lecturers insists that windows versions as late as XP would permanently leak memory if the process did not clean up after itself.

I find this hard to believe. If this was ever true, how long ago was this solved, and which operating systems pioneered it?

Comment: Look into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720014/what-operating-systems-will-free-the-memory-leaks?rq=1

Comment: Even W95 cleaned up process resources on termination, (assuming it managed to not BSOD first:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with 'how long ago' nor did any operating system 'pioneer' it. It has to do with how the operating system in question works. There are probably plenty of operating systems nowadays that still leak un-freed memory on process finish (though they're likely to be embedded systems).

For example, if I am remembering correctly, some DOS programs used to deliberately 'leak' memory to install interrupt handlers. A program would be run, allocate some memory and copy some code to it, modify the interrupt table and return without free-ing the memory. DOS doesn't clean up the memory so the interrupt handlers remain resident in memory.

I don't believe there was an operating system that 'started it all'. I believe freeing un-freed resources after a process exits is just a side effect of operating systems implementing [process isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_isolation).

I don't think it's even a problem in many cases so it's a bit misleading for you to refer to the issue as 'solved' or 'unsolved'. On an embedded system for example, where all the processes are carefully written to free all allocated memory when it exits, there's no reason to implement anything that tracks which process owns which memory and do possibly expensive un-freed resource checking and clean up. On such a system, the operating system not cleaning up after a process is perfectly valid - it isn't a problem to begin with.